# project is not showing in Eclipse after cloning repository

Tags: eclipse, git

I changed my workspace to 'C:/folder/proj_folder' , I then cloned the rep to this folder and I can see now the project in "C:/folder/proj_folder/myProject".
But I don't see anything in my package explorer in Eclipse.
I tried making a new local branch from the local Development branch. Then I tried to pull/fetch the project to this new branch from the remote Development branch but this option doesn't exist..

What am I doing wrong?

I can see in eclipse in the Git Repositories window the rep and the working directory folder with all my project. Should I import all of that manually ?

Comment: U can try go through this Tutorial https://youtu.be/7Vy6sPkzwIg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workspace and your local clones should not physically overlap. Doing so introduces limitations and confusion. Working with a repository that exists remotely correctly is a two-step process: [clone](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Cloning_a_Repository) it and then [import](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Importing_projects) projects from the clone into the workspace, without physically copying them around. Assuming the project's Eclipse metadata files (e.g. `.project` and `.classpath` for Java Projects) were committed into the repository, you'll have a nice starting point.

Comment: Thanks!
Just a couple of questions on the matter:
1. In which case then do I need to use "pull/fetch" ? After I already imported a project ,and have moved to another branch?
2. What is the difference if I create a new branch from a remote branch or from a local branch ? In both cases the new branch seems to appear as a local branch.

Comment: Those are really more general questions on how to use git, which deserve a separate question or visiting a tutorial of some kind.